# Why can't I read data from file where i wrote text. C

Tags: c, character-encoding

I'm new in C so i got confused a little bit. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FILENAME "/var/note"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int userid = getuid();
  int fd = open(FILENAME, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
  write(fd, &userid, 4);
}
```

Basically I'm writing UID in a text file. But when I try to actually open note file (with hand) It gives me error which says:

> The file you opened has some invalid characters. If you continue editing this file you could corrupt this document.
>   You can also choose another character encoding and try again.

I can't figure out why does it give me this error (when i actually wrote some text in this file) and how to solve it. In my opinion the problem is in character encoding but I don't know which one to use. Sorry if question sounds silly. Thank you.

Comment: You're writing the binary representation of an `int`, which isn't text.

Comment: Not very sure, but maybe encoding issue? Did you try with `fopen()`/`fprintf()`/`flose()` trio?

Comment: ohh... Now i get it thank you. So the file would contain 4 byte number in binary right?

Comment: It will contain 4 bytes. It's up to you how you interpret them. Don't forget to close the file.

Comment: need fclose()? do fclose and then see the result

Comment: Is it possible for me to write the number itself instead of binary number?

Comment: Why don't you use `fopen/fprintf`? It will be easier.

Comment: @Subinoy `close` rather than `fclose` in his case.

Comment: Yes @EugeneSh. you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write(fd, &userid, 4);`

You are writing 4 bytes of data from the memory starting at the beginning of your `userid` variable which is an `int`.

Let's say your userid is `42`, your [LSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit) is on the right (in human reading order) and your architecture is in [Big endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Your variable contains these 4 bytes:

```
0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 0000  0010 1010
```

You are writing these 4 bytes inside of your file, which results in these characters:

```
NUL NUL NUL *
```

Your notepad warns you because having `NUL` in a file is not normal (reminder: this is what is written for guid 42, *YMMV*)

Comment: Is it possible for me to write the number itself instead of binary number?

Comment: @Ojs did I mention about `fprintf()`?

Comment: If you are insisting on binary access, use `sprintf` into a buffer and then write the buffer to the file.